# Reading commands from text file and passing it into Script in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have a file.txt whose output is

```
declare -a Pool=("Minland" "Tucson" "Vancouver")
declare -a Library=("lib1" "lib2" "lib3")
declare -a Name=("Guru" "Albert" "Jeff")
declare -a Email=("guru@abc.com,Narendra@abc.com" "abc@def.com" "ghi@abc.com")
declare -a Subject=("   Finland Media Rotation" "       Tucson Media Rotation" "        Vancouver Media Rotation")
```

I want to use these outputs as the command to my other file.
Below is my effort.

```
cat Hello.txt | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c sh Media.sh
```

It doesn't give any output.

then alternate I have tried is appending like below which work but I know it's not the correct way.

```
cat file.txt Media.sh > out.sh
chmod +x out.sh
sh out.sh
```

So, please help me with the best option.

Comment: **1** When you execute `sh` it runs its own shell. Anything done in there (in terms of variables, etc) is local to that shell and can’t be seen in the calling shell. **2** `sh` doesn’t have arrays, and thus no `declare -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can source the content of your file.txt file into the script Media.sh with the next instruction as first instruction of your Media.sh file:

```
. file.txt
```